# How do I set up a Jenkins CI server to run automated BDD selenium tests using a remote webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, github, jenkins, remote-server

I'm new to Jenkins and am trying to set up a server to run selenium tests from a GitHub repo. I'm sure that I'm doing something wrong, likely several things, but haven't been able to figure it out.

I have configured the selenium plugin to use the default Selenium hub port 4444.

[Project GitHub Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3naSj.png)

Can't figure out why I'm getting this error. The credentials match the created username and ssh key. I can even access the repo by clicking on `GitHub` in the project dashboard.

[Project Shell Execution Steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hv8X6.png)

The before-build execution steps. These are the commands I use in the terminal to run the tests locally.

When I build the job it gives the following log:

```
 Started by <user>
 Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/Tutorial
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
 Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/<repo address>.git # timeout=10
 Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/<repo address>.git
 > git --version # timeout=10
 using GIT_SSH to set credentials 
 > git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/<repo address>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
 hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.com/<repo address>.git
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:809)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1076)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1107)
 at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:496)
 at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1281)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:604)
 at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
 at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:529)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
 at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
 at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
 Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress https://github.com/<repo address>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
 stdout: 
 stderr: remote: Invalid username or password.
 fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/<repo address>.git/'

 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1877)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1596)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:71)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:348)
 at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:807)
 ... 11 more
 ERROR: null
 Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Please put a [mcve] in the question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Would you like an example of the tests I am trying to run? What example would help?

Comment: from the error it says it failed to authenticate with git so its the first thing you need to fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SSH key for Jenkins to authenticate try using SSH version e.g. `git@github.com:FOO/BAR.git` instead of HTTPS one.